# Fixed duration is inactive

Tags: tasks, microsoft-project, microsoft-project-2007

In summary task information, Task type is set on " fixed duration" and is inactive (I can't change it). How can I change the duration?

Answer (score 0):

In Auto Scheduled mode, the durations for Summary tasks are *calculated* based on the span of the subtasks. Since it is a calculated field the task Type is Fixed Duration.

In Manually Scheduled mode, the Summary task duration can be manually changed. In that case it is still a fixed duration.